# Partially avoid class template parameter (deduce from constructor argument)

Tags: c++, class, templates

is there a way to avoid specifying a class template parameter if the type is being used in the constructor's argument?

I have:

```
template< typename T, typename X >
class myclass {
  myclass( typename X ) {};
  X myfunct() { return X(); };
};
```

so is there some design pattern to make it possible to instantiate myclass using just

```
myclass< TType > myclass_object( x_object );
```

instead of

```
myclass< TType, XType > myclass_object( x_object );
```

Thanks to you template programming experts, this stuff sometimes really freaks me out.

**Edit: added function with X return type to make situation clearer.**

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do that in this way;) EDIT: I would use factory method, instead. Template functions can be partially instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you don't need to know the second type for the rest of your class.

```
template< typename T >
class myclass {
  template < typename X >
  myclass( typename X ) {};
};
```

This works because the second template is a function, and for functions the compiler will deduce the template arguments from the types of the regular arguments if it can. In this case it can.

Comment: But I need to know them, that's why they are class template parameters and not function template parameters.

Comment: If you want to stack-construct them and they have to be template parameters then there's no way to deduce them. If you don't *need* the X type outside of your constructor, you can get away with this. You can also create an internal helper object (related: pImpl) to contain whatever you want to do with X that needs to be type-aware.

Comment: I have added a function to reflect my situation better.

Comment: Hmm... I'm pretty sure that it's impossible now. You need to know X for the return type of that function so it needs to be part of the class signature, and you can't derive it. An ugly combo of a macro and a decltype might work - #define OBJX(objname, T, f) myclass<T, decltype(f)> objname(f); - but I really not recommend trying it as it won't make anything clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a helper function that deduces the argument types and explicitly specifies the class instantiation. See `std::make_pair` for an example.

Comment: mm, in this case having a helper function template doesn't make the code easier..., I was hoping for some proxy template magic.

Answer (score 0):

Sort answer: no. `myclass<X>` and `myclass<Y>` cannot be deduced by construction from `Z` because `Z` might convert to either `X` or `Y`.

```
myclass<int> x (123);
myclass<float> x (123);
```

You *need* a helper function or a complete type.

```
template <typename T> myclass<T> make_myclass (const T &);
```